# libtinfow.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: r, centos7

Conda was used to install R in my centos 7 sysytem. conda install r
the version of installed r  is r-3.4.1.

However, when I use r, there have a error output. `"/usr/local/bin/miniconda3/lib64/R/bin/exec/R: error while loading shared libraries: libtinfow.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"`

Some tests have been used according to search by google use the keyword `"libtinfow.so.6".`

Only two information can be found. They have no help to me.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81pKc.png)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on a recent centos installation. But I think this has nothing to do with centos, but rather to misconfiguration related to different R packages version. To solve the problem, I just uninstall all the R related packages and gxx and gcc packages using "conda uninstall ". Than I installed R using "conda install -c r r", which force to install gcc and gxx within the same process.